# call_user_func inside a function in a class method doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to call a function that is inside of another function that is inside a class.

```
class Some_class extends CI_Controller {
    public function file($action){
        function add(){ 
            $content = "Content";
            $data = array('html'=>$content);
            $this->output->append_output(json_encode($data));
        }
        call_user_func($action);
    }
}
```

This returns nothing.

I need to call the function `add()`, and isn't working, even if I just put the `add()`rather than the `call_user_func()`. But the idea is call every function inside the function `file()`.

Comment: Well, how are you actually *calling* the function? What's in `$action`?

Comment: I'm passing add to the action.

Comment: If the method is public, people can type in any PHP function they want and it could execute (albeit, with no parameters). `http://example.com/some_class/file/phpinfo` Did you consider that? Why is it set up like this, what are your actual goals? It seems unnecessary to use any of the `call_user_func` functions here.

Comment: yes, but in the __constructor() i have a session verification that block unauthorized user. But thanks for the tip.

Comment: Authorized or not, you should verify that you want the `$action` called by comparing it to known, safe function names. Currently you don't even have error handling for when the argument is missing.

Answer (score 1):

You want to pass a [callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback). Say that `action` is a method of `MyClass`. You would then use:

```
$my_class = new MyClass();

call_user_func(array($my_class, 'action'));
```

Comment: It looks like he wants to call `add()` from the `file()` method, I guess by passing `add` to the first parameter. Actually I have no idea.

Comment: Point well taken. I was trying to overlook the syntax and cut back to the basics :-)

Answer (score 1):

While I have never personally used this function, I believe that it doesn't work because you're not returning anything.

If the function $action is supposed to return a value, then write:

```
return call_user_func($action);
```

Otherwise (if it puts a value in a param), it would require a param, which would work something like:

```
call_user_func($action, $param);
return $param;
```

Maybe I misunderstand what you're trying to do though.

Comment: It's a Codeigniter thing: `$this->output->append_output()` doesn't need a return value - it just appends to the Ouput class's `final_output` property. It's really unclear what the OP is trying to do, so he may not even be calling `add()` and would indeed need the `return`. So, good point.